# Node: send client-side data back to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Beginner Node question.

I'm running a Node/Express app, and I want to send client-side data back to the server.

What's the best way to do this?

Do I need something like [Socket](http://socket.io/#home) (not that I really understand what Socket is), or is there an in-built Node way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej richard

The built in way is the standard http way ... ajax or normal form post.

if you want to use ajax (the one without a page refresh) i suggest u use
jquery for that.

if you want to do a form post just write a form and point it to a url
thats capable of taking the data (write a app.post("/bla", .... handler in express)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to extend the question, but what advantage does Socket give over standard Ajax, then?

Comment: the ability to push data from the server to the client. like a chat app wuld need for ex.